# Why is my query returning varying results, and how do I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Tags: r, postgresql, dbplyr, rpostgresql

When I run a simple `count(*)` using dbplyr, I get anywhere from 40k to 70k at a result:

```
> tbl(con,sql("select count(*) from app_public.members"))
# Source:   SQL [1 x 1]
# Database: postgres ...
    count
  <int64>
1   62859
> tbl(con,sql("select count(*) from app_public.members"))
# Source:   SQL [1 x 1]
# Database: postgres ...
    count
  <int64>
1   54141
```

This takes less than a second to run, so I don't think it is a time-out issue. When I run this on my database (via DataGrip), the answer is consistently 108646. I confirmed I have the same connection host, port, dbname, and username/password.

The table type of `my_schema.members` is "BASE TABLE", and based on the information_schema, there are no tables named the same. As far as I can tell, this is the only table that acts this way.

What could be happening? How do I help my IT department troubleshoot?

Comment: **Add answers to following as text update to question text**. 1) Run this *When I run this, I get ...* where? 2)  How are you retrieving the results from the query? 3) What do you get when you run the query in `psql`? 4) I guessing the `Warning` is coming from a failure to issue a `commit`.

Comment: I think the warning is superfluous to your problem, though you may be able to get rid of the warning by switching from `dbSendQuery` to `dbExecute` ... not sure.

Comment: This seems like a connection issue rather than a question about R. Might it be your query times out and you just get partial results before it finishes running?

Comment: @r2evans thanks! You are right that is superfluos and did fix the warning.